# excel vba - how to copy all the fields in a pivot table to other cells in the same sheet

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table

I have a user form in excel with a combo box and when I choose something in the combobox it automatically updates a pivot table in a certain sheet. 
now I want to take all the fields that are now in the pivot table and copy them to another coulmn. I need to write it in vb but for some reason it wont copy the cells. that is my code:

```
Set x = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable4.1").DataBodyRange.Cells
x.Copy
Application.Goto Reference:="pivot_paste"
x.Paste
```

everthing works fine except the last line for some reason
please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`x.Paste` means to copy it to the range x, which is clearly not what you want. Something like this should work:

```
Set x = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable4.1").DataBodyRange.Cells
x.Copy Destination:=ActiveSheet.Range("pivot_paste")
```